# How do I create a selection from a pattern or a fill layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, patterns

I am trying to create a selection from a pattern. I created the pattern, then a fill layer, now I have this:

[image]

What I am *actually* trying to achieve is to delete lines from a picture. The solution I imagined to do this is to create such a pattern, then create a selection from this pattern, and use the selection to delete lines from the image (here, background layer).

1. How to create a selection from a pattern? Select range does not work. Actually select from fill layer does not work. If this is not the right way is there another way to create a selection from a pattern, for instance by duplicating the selected area somehow?
2. Is there another (easier/better) way to delete lines from a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it. I just created a normal layer, filled with the pattern, then selected the color range (black - or white also works) then selected the picture layer and hit delete.